# Concise way to get only global and local shell variables (not functions or env. variables) in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

How would I go about getting the values of local and global variables in Bash, skipping any functions and environment variables?

`declare -p` gives me the whole bunch. But it's not clear whether I can rely on the output format of `declare -p`. From the `help declare` output it is also not obvious whether whether `declare -p` may include functions or not. Experimentation suggests it doesn't.

Example: there are variables whose output will be similar to:

```
declare -- VARNAME="Variable value"
```

... and others where the options to `declare` are given instead of `--`, e.g.:

```
declare -ir UID="197609"
```

Now, if I *knew* that I can rely on this format for the output of `declare`, I could simply use a `while` loop similar to this one to limit the output to read-only integer variables:

```bash
while read -r decl opts keyval; do
    if [[ "$opts" == *ir* ]]; then # could obviously also be case/esac
        echo "$keyval"
    fi
done < <(declare -p)
```

... and thereby weed out the types of variables I am not interested in.

**Question:** But *can* I rely on this to be the case? If not, what other *concise* method exists to filter the variables by some given criteria?

NB: I am interested in Bash >=5.0 and I am currently using 5.2.15 on my machine.

Comment: `declare -p -i` lists integer variables, `declare -p -r` lists read-only variables, but `declare -p -ri` is an "OR" (union) operation between these two sets rather than a "AND" (intersection), so that would only be partially helpful.

Comment: @Kusalananda indeed. I tried a number of these and found no generic way to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the type of variables using `typeset` / `declare` `-p`. `+F` excludes functions, and variables set through the environment are marked `-x`, so we can regex the hell out of this:

```bash
declare -p +F | grep -Ev '^declare -x'
```

should you just need the names:

```bash
declare -p +F | sed -n  's/^declare -[^x] \([^=]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this trick might help to remove functions and by extension other stuff. Although neither is "in Bash", given `grep` or `sed` are used as external tools (but my wording may have been the issue). I have my reasons why I want to avoid external tools in this particular case, even though you may not deem my reasons valid. Also, it's odd that this doesn't seem to work to exclude exported variables, e.g. with `+x`. Seems inconsistent (as per the comment by Kusalananda). Do you know if I can rely on the format of the `declare -p` output? It would allow a Bash-only solution ...

Comment: Nobody can know how the bash developers plan to develop bash for the next 30 years, but as far as I can tell, that format has never fundamentally changed (nor would it make sense for it to do). Instead of `grep` or `sed` you can of course also use bash-builtin `for` to go through the lines, and use `test` / `[` to test for string pattern matching. That's up to you to develop, though. If you need a payload to work on a machine without GNU `grep` but with GNU `bash`, the general applicability of every proposed solution is basically null, so I'll let you develop that part of the solution yourself

Comment: Note that you asked for the most *concise* solution, and any bash-only solution is going to be *less* concise ;)

Comment: note that the output could also be e.g. `declare -irx ...`. For variables that were only imported from the environment and not touched in the script you'd only see `-x`, but if the script does `declare -i foo=42` while `foo` is already in the environment, you get `declare -ix foo="42"`. Unless the script goes through the bother to `unset foo` first.

Comment: @ilkkachu But I think that's fine, right? OP asks for `foo` in that case, right? It just "shadows" the environment `foo`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, right, I don't know what they'd like to do in that case. I guess there's the inverse case too, where any normal variable could get the export attribute if it was set in the original environment, and then get ignored by filter. Unless the script `unset`s it, of course. Sh-like shells don't really keep envvars and shell-internal vars that separate. Sure, likely not such an issue, but, anyway.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's a fair point that we don't know about the future, but I was hoping that I missed some sort of documentation where this format is specified or so.

Comment: Note that it's relying on undocumented and likely unintended behaviour. `declare -F` is meant to list functions without their definitions (poor choice when `-F` is for floating point variables in other shells). If you look at the source, what happens with `-p +F` is that the `+` turns on `nodefs`, but also means the fact that we ask for functions is recorded for `flags_off`, so `flags_on` remains unset, so with `-p` we end up listing variable attributes with `nodefs` set and that `nodefs` flag seems to be honoured for some types of variables and not others.

Comment: Note that `declared -p` alone excludes functions already.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`:

```
comm -23 -- <(compgen -v | sort) <(compgen -e | sort)
```

Where `comm` subtracts the `e`xported variables from the list of all `v`ariables.

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -roC1 -- ${(k)parameters[(R)^*export*]}
```

`$parameters` is a special associative array that maps parameter names to their list of type and attributes.

Here, we `print`, `r`aw, `o`rdered on `1`  `C`olumn the `k`eys of that associative array for which the value does not contain `export`.

You might want to also exclude the `special`, `hide`, or `undefined` (ready to be autoloaded) ones.